# mysqli to PDO Translation

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

The following code is for me at least straight forward. I want to to achieve the same thing using PDO. However, try as I may I simply can't get my head around the concept. Could someone please explain?

```
//Connect to a database.
$link  = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't connect to database.");

//Delete from the multiple tables. 
$sql = "DELETE FROM table1, table2, tables3, tables4 WHERE id='75'";
$result = mysqli_query($link , $sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, using prepared statements just for showing as id = 75 is no user input - but that's the better way and using a transaction - in case you want to delete/update/insert more data at a time this is way faster.

```
$id = 75;


try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME , DB_USER, DB_PASS);




$pdo->beginTransaction();

$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = :id');
$st->execute(array(':id', $id));
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = :id');
$st->execute(array(':id', $id));
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM table3 WHERE id = :id');
$st->execute(array(':id', $id));
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM table4 WHERE id = :id');
$st->execute(array(':id', $id));

$pdo->commit();
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {

    die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');

}
```

**SIDENOTE:**

To write less, do it like this:

```
$array = array('table1','table2','table3','table4');
foreach ($array as $table) {
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id');
    $st->execute(array(':id', $id));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, it's much clearer to me now. The shorthand is definitely preferable. I always like economic code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multiple table delete in a single query Try with foreach in PDO

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$tables = array("table1","table2","table3","table4");
foreach($tables as $table) {
  $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = :id";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);  // $id or '75'
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. A wrapper that can't do multiple deletes. So this is progress?